# Check for existence any string inside html element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm aware you can do something like this:

```
$('.document-content p:has(br)').next('p').addClass("newClass")
```

to check whether a `p` tag has a `br` tag inside:

```
<p>
<br>
</p>
```

How to check if there's also for the existence of **ANY** string inside?

```
<p>
"Some text"
<br>
</p>
```

(The reason is, I want to remove all `br` inside the `p` tags that have a string inside.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:contains` selector:

```
$('.document-content contains("some text")').next('p').addClass("newClass")
```

If the string to find is stored in a variable you would need to concatenate it in the selector:

```
var searchString = 'some text';
$('.document-content contains("' + searchString + '")').next('p').addClass("newClass")
```

> The reason is, I want to remove all `br` inside the `p` tags that have a string inside.

In this case you can get the `text()` of the element and overwrite the `html()` with it:

```
$('.document-content').html(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

Or

```
$('.document-content').html($('.document-content').text());
```

Both the above will work, the latter is shorter but (IMO) uglier and makes another DOM request.

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eys6kce2/)

Comment: `$('.document-content').html($('.document-content').text());` this will remove all other tags as well from the p tag, for example `<b>abcd</b>` would be also removed

Comment: @NaeemShaikh that's correct. If OP can clarify if that's not intended behaviour, I'll amend.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like thi https://jsfiddle.net/joL9xh2r/

```
$('p').each(function(i,ele){
    if($(ele).text().replace(/\s/g, '').length>0)
    {
        alert($(ele).attr('id')+' has string');
    }
})
```

Here are two paragraphs , one with string inside, and one without text, you can check if the paragraph contains a string using `text()`, Now you can do whatever you want within the if condition, its only true whan there is a string inside the `p` element

> Now if you want to removethe br tag , then you can do this,

https://jsfiddle.net/joL9xh2r/1/

```
$(ele).html($(ele).text())
```

But, Remember this will remove all the html tags inside, for Example https://jsfiddle.net/joL9xh2r/2/,
here you have

```
<p id='x'>
"Some text"
    <br/>
    <b>abc</b>
</p>
```

A bold tag within `p` , so the above solution, and the one suggested by rorry will remove the b tag as well.

> The best way to remove **only** br this would be

https://jsfiddle.net/joL9xh2r/3/

```
$('p').each(function(i,ele){
    if($(ele).text().replace(/\s/g, '').length>0)
    {
        alert($(ele).attr('id')+' has string');

       $(ele).find('br').remove();


    }
})
```